# Reorder Listbox and save new order to SQLiteDatabase

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, listbox

I was wondering if somebody knows the right approach to save the position of reordered items in a listbox to a SQLitedatabase so when the wpf app opens next time it shows the saved order.
Where do I save the order and how does it update the database when I change the position of the items in the listbox again.

Answer (score 0):

1- define a column in table called sequence or any suitable name you like
2- when you fetch data from database, always order by this field
3- when you change in app, you have two options
- you change the order on every change event that can be too many calls to database 
- once you are done with ordering, you can have a save button or on leave event of the screen and send the data to database with the order and just set the sequence in database.

This way next time you get it, it will be saved sequence.

Comment: What value do I put in the column, an integer? and how does this value change when the list is reordered?

Comment: Yes an integer value. Like I said you can pass the two items in every change event so that you can swap their Sequence in database as well or you can done on a button when you are done ordering all of them. One simple way can be that remove the existing ordering and add new one with their ordering or use update statement to update sequence based on the item id